# What is the best way to maintain a git public repo fork within a private repo?

Tags: git

Is there a way to fork a public git repo and track them **within** a private repo? The use case here is to have one private repo while maintaining the ability to pull and merge from the public repo.

Example Directory layout:

```
myPrivateProject:
  - workDir1
  - workDir2
  - publicRepoDir (cloned from some public repo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [subtree merge](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html).

Comment: Friendly reminder since you're new here: when an answer solves your question, you should click the check-mark to the left of it to "accept" the answer.

Comment: @Aditya: If you're not looking to modify the public repo, just include it within yours, you'd want to use a [submodule](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)