# Best way to manage external git repos within a private repo

Tags: git

I'm still a novice when it comes to git and so while I did see the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287157/what-is-the-best-way-to-maintain-a-git-public-repo-fork-within-a-private-repo)  it didn't really give me enough understanding to really do this. Here's my basic problem:

I have several environments (development, test, production) that I move code through. In most cases I develop in development and then push the private repos up to bitbucket (since I can have free private repos). Then I pull this down from bitbucket in the other environments I need the updated code. That's fine; works as you'd expect.

The problem is when I within the private repo i have an "externals" directory with a bunch of public repo's hanging off of it (as the picture below illustrates):

[image: example repo dir structure]

I want the checkout status of all public repos to be the same at any given time. So let's say that public repo 1 in my development environment was 10 commits behind the master; when I pull the private repo into my test environment I not only want the private repo to get pulled down (no problem there) but I want to pull down public repo 1 to the same commit level as existed in development.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using submodules? And are you using branches, or multiple repos?

Comment: Nope. Up to now I'd just done a .gitignore on the "externals" directory and then manually synced the files in the externals directory w/o using git.

Comment: And what about branching? Are you using branches for your different environments or multiple repos?

Comment: No not really. I do have a public repo that I've forked and pushed my code into a new branch. Outside of this one exception I haven't really used branches much yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preface, if you aren't using branches for your dev, test, production areas, and are instead managing multiple repositories for the same code base, you should look into simply using branches. This will make it much easier to manage the code, instead of pushing the code around to different places.

There is a "model" called git-flow that talks about this concept in depth: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

As for your external public repos, the git submodule feature sounds like exactly what you are after. By adding the repos as submodules, your main repo will track them to their commits. So like you said, if public repo A is 10 commits behind and that is where you commit it in your main repo, it will check out again at that same location.

Submodule repo changes require that you first make changes to the external repo, push those changes, pull them to your main repo submodule, and then commit them in the main repo (to track the changed commit).

There are more in depth submodule tutorials out there [(here is one)](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/), but a general overview is like this:

```
cd mainRepo
git submodule add http://git.domain.com/repo external/submoduleA
```

This will clone your public repo into external/submoduleA. From here you could checkout a different commit if you want. But when you are ready, you can add and commit this in your main repo. Now when you clone this main repo out again someone else, you would do:

```
git clone http://git.domain.com/myMainRepo --recursive
```

The `recursive` option tells it to also continue checking out all of the submodules. You could leave this off and init them as a second step. But I leave that to you to explore all the options of the `submodule` command.